# Multiple line pattern/ Data extraction

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following header below in the about 100,000 files, I have already extracted each line separately and combined each record in excel, so my time crunch is over and i am now looking to for an expedient method of data extraction.

X-RSMF-Generator: RSMF Generator Sample Library

X-RSMF-Version: **1.0.0**

X-RSMF-EventCount: **53**

X-RSMF-BeginDate: **2022-09-20T04:33:11-04:00**

X-RSMF-EndDate: **2022-09-20T16:47:56-04:00**

X-RSMF-GroupID: **GRP000000118**

X-RSMF-SecondaryGroupID: **GRP000000118_D_20220920**

X-RSMF-ContainsDeleted: **False**

X-RSMF-Application: **Native Messages**

X-RSMF-Participants: **Person One <5156242756> Person two, Person**

**three person.three@gmail.com <21243210277> Person four *** <345278652345>**

MIME-Version: 1.0

Not all lines are present in all files and the last field can contain more than one line.  MIME-Version: 1.0 - I think we can use **MIME-Version: 1.0** as the stop. I also only need to data for each line entry. everything before the ": "  (colon space) can be ignored as those are the field headings.

I started out using sed, thinking I could just concatenate each line and pipe to AWK. to make each column.

```
#!/bin/sh

shopt -s nullglob
FILES=/mnt/c/Temp/rsmf/*.rsmf

for f in $FILES

do
    #echo "Processing $f"
    sed -rn \
    -e '/^X-RSMF-BeginDate:/{
        s/X-RSMF-BeginDate: //
        s/T/ /
        s/-0[45]:00/ /
        s/X-RSMF-Application://
        h
        #p
        }' \
    -e '/^X-RSMF-EndDate:/{
        s/X-RSMF-EndDate: //
        s/T/ /
        s/-0[45]:00/ /
        H
        #p
        }' \
     -e '/^X-RSMF-GroupID:/{
        s/X-RSMF-GroupID: //
        H
        x
        s/\r\n//gp
        }' \
         $f
done
```

Results -

```
2022-10-05 12:54:27 2022-10-05 12:54:27 GRP000000001
2022-10-05 11:48:18 2022-10-05 11:48:18 GRP000000002
```

Before spending time on this, I wanted to seek recommendations on the best approach and practice for this particular project.

Thoughts??

Comment: When asking questions about text processing, please use block code formatting for verbatim reproduction of your input example. Also be sure to provide the desired output for the included input. That way, contributors can test proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F': ' 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}$1=="MIME-Version"{exit}{print $2}END{print "\n"}' file
```

Comment: No sure how this does what it does,, We would need all data on one line for every files and for the time/date fields tit cuts off the time after 2 digits.

Comment: Post edited accordingly. For the date, you can use `sub()` or `substr()`

Comment: Only got "01" - on my end, on the field that I  tried it on.

Answer (score 0):

The following is pretty hacky and brute-force method and there's probably a better way of doing it (but I'd need to know more about your data and why you're even mentioning Excel - if the data was originally in a spreadsheet, there are perl modules for extracting data directly from Excel or Open/Libre Office etc), but it does work with the sample data you provided.

It can process any number of input files.

It has been written to use TAB (`\t` or Ctrl-I or `^I`) as the output field separator, rather than a space **because your field data can contain spaces**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  s/^\s*|\s*$//g;  # strip any leading and trailing whitespace
  next if /^$/;    # ignore all blank lines

  # split input line into @F array
  # $F[0] will contain the field name and
  # $F[1] will contain the field data
  # The field separator is a quite-forgiving zero-or-more spaces followed by
  # a colon followed by one-or-more spaces. This should cope with most minor
  # variants caused by manual extraction from Excel. 
  my @F = split /\s*:\s+/;

  # print the data at end of each input record (file)
  if (/^MIME-Version/) {
    # add space-separated @participants array to end of @record array
    push @record, join(" ", @participants);

    # print @record array, tab-separated
    print join("\t", @record), "\n";

    # clear both arrays, ready for next input file
    @record=();
    @participants=();
    next;
  };

  # fix up the date format
  if (/^X-RSMF-(Begin|End)Date/) {
    $F[1] =~ s/T/ /;
    $F[1] =~ s/-0[45]:00$//;
  };

  if (/^X-RSMF-Participants/) {
    # participants need to be handled differently because this field can
    # be multi-line.  Store in a separate @participants array
    push @participants, $F[1];

  } elsif ($#F == 0) {
    # lines without a field name get added to @participants array
    push @participants, $_;

  } else {
    # all other fields get added to @record array
    push @record, $F[1];
  }
}
```

Save it to a file, e.g. `rsmf2tab.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x rsmf2tab.pl`, and run it as, e.g.

`./rsmf2tab.pl  /mnt/c/Temp/rsmf/*.rsmf`

or if your .rsmf files are in multiple subdirectories:

`find /mnt/c/Temp/rsmf/ -name '*.rsmf' -exec /path/to/rsmf2tab.pl {} +`

Sample output with two copies of you sample data (as file1.rsmf and file2.rsmf) as input, piped through `cat -A` to show the tabs as `^I`:

```
$ ./rsmf2tab.pl *.rsmf | cat -A
RSMF Generator Sample Library^I1.0.0^I53^I2022-09-20 04:33:11^I2022-09-20 16:47:56^IGRP000000118^IGRP000000118_D_20220920^IFalse^INative Messages^IPerson One <5156242756> Person two, Person three person.three@gmail.com <21243210277> Person four <345278652345>$
RSMF Generator Sample Library^I1.0.0^I53^I2022-09-20 04:33:11^I2022-09-20 16:47:56^IGRP000000118^IGRP000000118_D_20220920^IFalse^INative Messages^IPerson One <5156242756> Person two, Person three person.three@gmail.com <21243210277> Person four <345278652345>$
```

---

BTW, you **really** do not want to do your `FILE=/mnt/c/Temp/rsmf/*.rsmf` followed by `for f in $FILES`.  That will break if any files contain any whitespace characters. And it's not necessary, anyway - just run `for f in /mnt/c/Temp/rsmf/*.rsmf` or (depending on what you're running), just pass all filename args to the command you're running without using a loop.

Comment: Cas,   I was avoiding a full script to complete this for the sake of expediency, but if it is the only method.  I guess it will have to be done. Thank for the feedback.  Since I used grep to export each  X-RSMF line, I need a method of combining all fields back into a records for all files.   I exported the file name and used excel to combine everything back into a table an used it for importing. This also took care of aligning records if there was line missing from the text file.

Comment: I wrote an even hackier perl one-liner, but I didn't like it (it made too many assumptions and minor variations in input broke it). Turned it into the simple script above instead.  BTW, it's the joining of the multiple lines of participants that made me go with this design, it was just easier (conceptually) to use multiple arrays.   BTW, I don't really see the distinction you're making about "avoiding a full script". sed scripts are scripts. awk scripts are scripts. perl scripts are scripts. some tasks require - or are done better - something more complex than just regex search & replace ops.

Comment: Also BTW, what was your original input file (the one you "used grep to export each X-RSMF line" from)?  It would probably be easier to write a script to convert directly from that to the tab-separated output above.